# Rust mismatched type error for outside of loop

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and pretty confused by this type error.
Here is my code:

```rust
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};

fn read(input: &mut String) {
    stdout().flush().expect("failed to flush");
    stdin().read_line(input).expect("failed to read");
}

fn main() {
    let mut num1 = String::new();
    let mut num2 = String::new();

    println!("what is the first number?");
    read(&mut num1);
    println!("what is the second number?");
    read(&mut num2);
    let mut operator = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("what is the operator[+-*/?]");
        read(&mut operator);
        let operator: char = operator.trim().chars().next().unwrap();
        let operators = String::from("+-*/");
        if !operators.contains(operator) {
            println!("unknown operator!!");
        } else {
            break;
        };
    }

    let num1: f32 = num1.trim().parse().unwrap();
    let num2: f32 = num2.trim().parse().unwrap();

    let result = match operator {
        '+' => num1 + num2,
        '-' => num1 - num2,
        '*' => num1 * num2,
        '/' => num1 / num2,
        _ => panic!("error in operator"),
    };

    println!("the result is {}{}{} = {} ", num1, operator, num2, result);
}
```

and here is the error from rust compiler:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:34:9
   |
34 |         '+' => num1 + num2,
   |         ^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found char
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `char`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:35:9
   |
35 |         '-' => num1 - num2,
   |         ^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found char
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `char`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:36:9
   |
36 |         '*' => num1 * num2,
   |         ^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found char
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `char`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:37:9
   |
37 |         '/' => num1 / num2,
   |         ^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found char
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `char`
```

I guess the reason why I got an error was because `operator` is type has been changed from `String` to `char` but I would like to use loop this until the input from stdin contains `+-*/`.

How can it possible?

Comment: [a simple solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a522b43c983425bb14a5a9edee5e6684) but your code will not do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program has a small mistake. You have defined operator twice in two different scopes. In outer scope it is a `String` and in inner scope it is `char`. You have used `match` operator in outer scope where it is `String` but you have matched with `char`.

Small tweak and here is the link [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8748d88e4e98e9635980b82f84796962)

Comment: thank you it worked however it still confuse me with the output of "unknown operator!!" even though i type either one of those operators.